# Swift NSPREDICATE not like value

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

EntityA: Gymnast
firstName
lastName

one to many MeetResults

EntityB: MeetResults
meetDate
barScore
beamScore
floorScore
vaultScore

I am loading all gymnasts who are set as active into the picker.  As I create an NSSET result.meetresults = meetScore.copy() as? NSSet which works fine I am trying to figure out how to remove a gymnast who already has a NSSET for this date.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
func getGymnasts() {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Gymnast")

        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "fullName", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

        let filter1 = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == %@", "Yes")

        let filter2 = NSPredicate(format: "ANY meetresults.meetDate != %@", "\(meetDateText.text!)")

        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [filter1, filter2])

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        //fetchRequest.predicate = filter1

        do {

            self.gymnastArray = try AD.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Gymnast]

            self.gymnastPicker.reloadAllComponents()


        } catch {

            fatalError("Fetch Failed")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Presumably `meetDate` is stored as a date, not a string?

Comment: No date is stored as String.

Comment: you verified the string formats? did you try subquery approach?

Comment: I have confirmed if I click on new to add another gymnast, and if say I have already added 3 gymnasts those are the only 3 I have to choose from in my picker. I am not find away to use (not equal) or (not like) a value.  Regardless of whether I use != or == it still bring back the 3 gymnasts I had added. let filter2 = NSPredicate(format: "ANY meetresults.meetDate != %@", "\(meetDateText.text!)")

Comment: so your aim is actually to return gymnasts who do not have a meet on a specified date?

Comment: Yes when it loads and you click new it will list all gymnasts you have entered from Gymnast VC that are set to Active = Yes in the picker.  Once you have added the NSSET associating the meet result to the gymnast the next time you go to add another gymnast for that meet I don't want a gymnast that is already added to be a choice in the picker.  Since I am doing the fetch to a many I was told I had to use ANY otherwise I get crash.  I tried ANY NOT meet results.meetDate but that crashes to.  Searching around, maybe I need to use a different format for my predicate.

Comment: and you have a many-to-many relationship between the Gymnast and the Meet ? It should probably be something like `"!(ANY meetresults.meetDate == %@)", "\(meetDateText.text!)"`

Comment: or `"SUBQUERY(meetresults, $m, $m.meetDate == %@).@count == 0"`

Comment: @Wain, thank you very much.  Been searching for awhile.  Here is what finally worked. let filter2 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(meetresults.meetDate, $m, $m.meetDate != %@).@count == 0")

Answer (score 0):

To-many relationships are awkward sometimes. You can use the subquery syntax to query the count of an internal fetch to find `Meet`s matching your criteria, then check there aren't any:

```
let filter2 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(meetresults.meetDate, $m, $m.meetDate == %@).@count == 0", meetDateText.text!)
```

Comment: Found slight issue.  This excludes them from any other meetresults.  Creating a new meet with different date and the picker will not list anyone that already has a meet result.

Comment: My original had ==, yours had != so it should have been working backwards

Comment: Thanks, must have been because I was calling my function and keying on date before I actually had date value, moved some items around and it seems to be working now but also added a similar one SUBQUERY(meetresults.meetName, $m, $m.meetName == %@).@count == 0"